# Facebook page access token with "Reading Permission" only

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I want to show the one latest shared post of my Facebook page in a website (text description + date of posting). I'm using Javascript (client-side only, PHP is not allowed because the website is not hosted in an Apache server). For that I need an Access Token with `Manage Pages` permission (correct me if I'm wrong please).

According to my researches, getting a token that doesn't expire in one month and that have `Manage Pages` permission (the only permission that grant reading a page feeds), require the creation of a Facebook app that include "Facebook login" and then waiting for the "Review Process" approval.

I don't have any intention to make people login since it's a static website. Is there a possibility to get a static access token that doesn't expire in an hour  and that have the permission of "reading page's feed", without creating the app, adding a privacy policy page URL for it, waiting for the review process, and making people login?

Comment: No, there is not. And as you were told in your previous question already, a page access token does not belong into client-side code.

Comment: @CBroe I wanted to be sure that there is no other alternative for making people login. Unfortunately, the "page plugin" don't show the posting date/time. Now I assume that there is no other possibility than using server-side or making people login.

Comment: Correct – there is no other way (no way without compromising security.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make A facebook App, get its `access_token` and then use this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{page-id}/feed?format=json&access_token={access_token}
```

or you can also use user access_token as well to read only. No need to make app in this scenario.

It will return in response

```
"data": [
  {
     "message": "Test",
     "created_time": "2015-09-28T10:36:09+0000",
     "id": "1631034803844937_1634777900137294"
  },
  {
     "message": "Testing Testing .. !! Helloo",
     "created_time": "2015-09-16T11:06:18+0000",
     "id": "1631034803844937_1631042857177465"
  }
],
```

Comment: Facebook App require users to login. I don't have any intention to make them login.

Comment: with access token you dont need people to be logged in.

Comment: Creating a Facebook app that have "Read Page Feed " (Manage Pages) permission require making people login when accessing the App before review and permission approval.

Comment: You dont need manage Pages permission as you are reading only,, you just need app access token which you will generate yourself in graph explorer

Comment: Ok thanks i will try that.

Comment: Hopfully it helps you, also you can ask any help regarding facebook development in future.

Comment: @SalmanAslam, you should mention in your answer how to get the basic app access token and explain that the manage_pages permission is not required (which is what I also thought from reading Facebooks poor documentation). Then Naourass should mark this as the accepted answer.