# Is it safe to make a Facebook Graph API Call from the Client using a Page Access Token?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I want to call Facebook's Graph API from the client to READ public posts on a page using a permanent Page Access Token.  I'm curious if this is safe (or how to make it safe).  From everything I've read and tried, an access token is required to perform this operation and none of Facebook's other functionality will suit my needs (see background below).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api/ suggests that it is safe to expose Page Access Tokens to the client, but I'm suspicious they're lying to me.

Background:
I'm working with a group that wants to display some posts from their Facebook feed on their WordPress website.  They don't want to display all posts, but rather filter them based on a hashtag.   I don't know a ton about WordPress, but I'm guessing I can't implement custom back-end API calls on a WordPress site.  Please suggest any alternative solutions that you might have!

Comment: Link about using a page access token without any permissions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039313/facebook-page-access-token-with-reading-permission-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access Token are like house keys, you NEVER leave them in front of the door. Which means, you should NEVER hardcode any Access Token. No matter if it is an App, Page or User Token. The docs do not state anywhere that it is ok to expose tokens, they just state how you can use a Page Token on that page in your question - but you cannot just hardcode it on the client.

Vulnerabilities: Without extra permissions, this would be more like a privacy issue, because you can get a lot more info with a Page Token (as the Page owner) than with a simple App Token.

Comment: The link I included says "One parameter of note is access_token which you can use to make an API call with a Page access token. App access tokens should never be used in this SDK as it is client-side, and your app secret would be exposed."  Unless I'm mistaken, this implies that client side calls are ok to make (somehow) with a page access token.  Is there a safe way to make a client side call using the JS SDK with the page access token such that it isn't hardcoded?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: no, that does not imply hardcoding tokens at all. again, tokens are like house keys. if you need to use a page token on the client, you need to generate the page token on the client - for the current user, with the /me/accounts endpoint.

Comment: Ahh.  That makes more sense.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible to do that kind of backend-calls with wordpress. And it would be the far better way, i think.

First you can use the WP-Cron to time your Facebook-Calls. You could create a Cron-Job every hour or so.

[WP Developer Scheduling WP Cron Events](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/scheduling-wp-cron-events/)

[Wordpress Codex wp_cron Function Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron)

[Kinsta Knowledgebase Wordpress Cron Job Tutorial](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/wordpress-cron-job/)

If you work first time with the WP-Cron have one thing in mind: WP-Cron depends on Site-Activity to be run. So if there is no Traffic on the Wordpress-Site, no Cron-Jobs are run. Here is a link how to add WP-Cron to your systems cron, so your API-Call will be called every time you intend to:

[WP Developer Hooking WPCron into System Task Scheduler](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-into-the-system-task-scheduler/)

The Cron-Job than can use the Wordpress HTTP API to do the call. You should check the Docs on the HTTP API and the wp_remote_request function in special.

[Wordpress Codex HTTP API](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API)

[WP Developer wp_remote_request Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_request/)

Or you could install the Facebook SDK with your Theme/Plugin.

I'm not sure about the security impacts when using a Page Access Token on the Client, but it seems to me, that it would be a better way to do that kind of job.

Comment: Thanks Carsten!  I would need to write a custom WP plugin in PHP to implement your solution, right?

Comment: It would be possible to implement it in a Theme also, but yeah. You need to use PHP.